# Rollback War on 'Why did our process cause us to miss our release date?'

Tags: support, moderation

The OP and one of the answerers keep alternating rollbacks to [this Question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/20884/why-did-our-process-cause-us-to-miss-our-release-date). It's getting a little ridiculous and unprofessional. Do we have rules in place for whose revision should be kept? The OP's because it's his/her question? The answerer's because it seems to generally improve the question (opinion-based as that statement may be)? Am I missing something?

Additionally, many of the comments are nothing but an unhelpful argument. While I do not believe any particular comment to be offensive enough to be flaggable, the entire conversation has a tone of disrespectfulness and is, overall, somewhat disheartening.

Do we have procedures for this?

Comment: Note [this comment](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/20884/why-did-our-process-cause-us-to-miss-our-release-date#comment26024_20884) which indicates we may have moved beyond this. I've retracted my close vote, but still think the comments need cleanup.

Comment: @CodeGnome ...which you can now do. Seriously, though, please do.

Answer (score 3):

### The Problem

The original question, which the OP keeps rolling back, is [off-topic](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for a number of reasons defined in our Help Center, including:

1. > "your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

   The OP says: "I blame our Agile approach for encouraging this particular problem, am I wrong?"
2. > "there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

   The OP says (emphasis mine): "I'm interested to hear **opinions** on where you think process has failed us here."
3. > Constructive subjective questions...have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone

   The original post does not exhibit these characteristics.
4. It may also be closable as "Too Broad" and "Opinion-Based" even if it were edited to avoid the preceding issues.

### The Solution

A number of people have provided modest edits which would enable the question to be on-topic and within community guidelines. The OP continues to roll them back. As a result, the question should simply be put on hold as off-topic for any one of the given reasons, at which time it can either be edited to conform to site guidelines, or eventually closed.

The extended discussions in comments should be vetted for relevance and tone. Comments are not for extended discussion, and should be cleaned up or moved when they become clutter or when they become too acrimonious. This requires moderator action (see blockers below).

### Blockers

However, despite close votes and flags from a number of community members, we seem to lack sufficient community/moderator participation at this time to handle the situation properly. We don't have a critical mass of close privileges, and flags are not being accepted or rejected. This may need to be brought up as a separate meta post.

Secondly, the sheer volume of comments makes it unlikely that the comment issue will be successfully addressed by individual flags or community moderation. Unless the diamond mods or the community want to be flooded with dozens of comment-flags, this is something that again needs explicit moderator intervention.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is rolling back the question to a format which does not meet the PM.SE guidelines for a **lot** of reasons include opinion-based.

Either the edits are enforced or the question needs closed.  It is clear the OP is now trolling the site and I have flagged this to Mods who have not taken action.

Comment: I do not believe the OP is actively trolling. I believe it more likely his(?) comments are a result of high emotions and lack of knowledge. The latter being rather the *point* of asking a question on SE. I could be wrong, but that is my takeaway from the comment-conversation.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ "Why must I add to an already-answered question?" - 'Must' is a strong word, but the reasoning is that questions on SE serve not only the OP, but those who come after as well. This is the same reason software recommendations are discouraged - they help the OP and no one else. While you do not have an *obligation* to add context to your question, doing so may improve the question for those who come after.