# Is it time to hold Moderator elections and share the Moderator burden at SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

After the [[rollback war]](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/788/10462) is it now time to hold another round of moderator elections to ensure we have consistent coverage across the PM SE?[1](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/788/10462)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mod team here has supported the idea of getting some backup, as the older answer here shows. Today, I am happy to announce that CodeGnome is joining the mod team here to provide them with that support!

[image: CodeGnome]

Please join me in welcoming this familiar face to the new job!

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no...

**Yes** - we definitely need a new moderator more at least!

**No** - on beta sites [there's no election process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102307/157692). Instead, the current mods / SE staff invite valuable members to help on the burden.

We're discussing the latter with the community managers and we expect to have news very soon.

Thanks!

**Update 1 (20/Mar):** Still waiting feedback from Stack Overflow community.

**Update 2 (09/Apr):** SE Community acknowledged the request and is reviewing community's most active members for suitable candidates.