# Please welcome your new pro tem moderator!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Your mod team here has supported the idea of getting some backup, as first discussed at [Is it time to hold Moderator elections and share the Moderator burden at SE?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/789/is-it-time-to-hold-moderator-elections-and-share-the-moderator-burden-at-se). Today, I am happy to announce that CodeGnome is joining the mod team here to provide them with that support!

[image: CodeGnome]

Please join me in welcoming this familiar face to the new job!

Comment: Welcome CG to the front line!

Comment: Welcome to the Mod team!!!